# Spring boot 2 Prometheus not pulling db metrics

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I am using spring boot2 with Prometheus. we are using Postgres as db. The Prometheus url is not fetching db metrics.

Any references would be very helpful.

I have tried

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {


  @Autowired
  HikariDataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics dbMeterics() {
    return new PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics(dataSource, "database-name");
  }

}
```

When I hit the end point /prometheus, I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.db.PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics.lambda$bindTo$1(PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics.java:101)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:40)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$3(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:235)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:69)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:183)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:216)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:137)
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.scrape(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
```

Comment: First thing is, check if the prometheus endpoint is up and running. If so, check the prometheus server log for any visible errors as to why a connection can not be made to the endpoint.

Comment: @Anoukh I have prometheus endpoint running but cannot find any datasource metrics.

Comment: can you give a bit more description on what you have done so far? i.e. How you have configured the Prometheus exporter etc.

Comment: @Anoukh, I have updated. Can you check

Answer (score 0):

In [line 101](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/8137d55d9cc3c9cc2e8e19c95ca92da38f0a5bc2/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/db/PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics.java#L101) the registry received via DI is used to build the pgMetrics object. Since you are getting the null pointer at this line, you might be missing the import of [Prometheus registry](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus#_installing) as a dependency.